# Specifying more than one interface in an nftables rule

Tags: iptables, firewall, nftables

I am in a situation where i have multiple interfaces for multiple docker networks. All docker networks should be able to access the internet, so i currently have the following nftables snippet:

```
chain forward {
  type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
  iifname docker0 ct state new accept comment "Accept forwards from docker0"
  iifname dck-backend ct state new accept comment "Accept forwards from dck-backend"
}
```

Since both rules are very similar but the interface name, i want to merge them into one, if possible. I tried to create a set of interface names:

```
set docker_interfaces {
    type ifname; flags interval;
    elements = {
      docker0,dck-backend
    }
  }
```

However, using the set in the rule with

```
iifname @docker_interfaces accept comment "Accept traffic from docker containers"
```

results in an error:

```
Okt 07 10:55:26 naugol nft[968969]: /etc/nftables.conf:40:5-11: Error: Byteorder mismatch: expected big endian, got host endian
Okt 07 10:55:26 naugol nft[968969]:     iifname @docker_interfaces accept comment "Accept traffic from docker containers"
Okt 07 10:55:26 naugol nft[968969]:     ^^^^^^^
Okt 07 10:55:26 naugol systemd[1]: nftables.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

How can i specify more than one interface in a rule, or do i really need several similar rules for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider inlining like so:

```
chain forward {
  type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
  iifname { "docker0", "dck-backend" } ct state new accept comment "Accept forwards from docker interfaces"
}
```

In addition you can use `define`

```
define interfaces = { "docker0", "dck-backend" }

chain forward {
  type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
  iifname $interfaces ct state new accept comment "Accept forwards from docker interfaces"
}
```

The can also be done on the command line with proper escaping:

`nft add rule ip filter forward iifname \{ "docker0", "dck-backend" \} ct state new accept comment "Accept forwards from docker interfaces"`